# Why there is a extra graph in a subplot which i did not mention anywhere

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, subplot

I have used the following code and in the last the figure of thee subplot why I am having an extra plot(red curve)

```
fig= plt.figure()
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size':24})
fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3)=plt.subplots(3,1,figsize= 
(20,24),sharex='row',sharey='col')


p1=plt.plot(x_axis,Clean_Current_TEST,"g",x_axis,Clean_Current_Prediction1,"r--")

    ax1.plot(x_axis,Clean_Current_TEST,"g",x_axis,Clean_Current_Prediction1,"r--", lw=3.0)

    ax2.plot(x_axis,Clean_Current_TEST,"g",x_axis,Clean_Current_Prediction2,"r--", lw=3.0)

    ax3.plot(x_axis,Clean_Current_TEST,"g",x_axis,Clean_Current_Prediction3,"b--", lw=3.0)#,x_axis,Clean_Current_Prediction3,"b--"

    ax1.legend(p1[:2], ["Experimental Output","Predicted Output1"],loc='best');
    ax2.legend(p1[:2], ["Experimental Output","Predicted Output2"],loc='best');
    ax3.legend(p1[:2], ["Experimental Output","Predicted Output3"],loc='best');

    ax1.title.set_text('Short Circuit Current of Clean Module vs 
    Time Graph')


    fig.text(0.5, 0.01, 'Time(hr)', ha='left', va='center')
    fig.text(0.01, 0.5, 'Clean Module Current(mA)', ha='center', 
    va='center', rotation='vertical')
    [enter image description here][1]
    plt.show()
    plt.tight_layout(pad=1)
```

(The last figure of the subplot)

[image]

Comment: Where is the plot?

Comment: I am unable to add it here, if you don't mind I can mail you the plot

Comment: It looks like the highlighted bits are graphed with this line `ax3.plot(x_axis,Clean_Current_TEST,"g",x_axis,Clean_Current_Prediction3,"b--", lw=3.0)#,x_axis,Clean_Current_Prediction3,"b--"`

Comment: Sure you can.  Just give it another whirl.

Comment: yes, the problem is with this line

Comment: sorry, but I did not understand what did you meant by "another whirl"

Comment: Also, for future reference, this: "if you don't mind I can mail you the plot" is faux pas on StackOverflow.  These questions and answers are for posterity, and as such they are expected to be self-contained as much as possible.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGIxC.png                 this is the link of the figure

Comment: "yes, the problem is with this line"  The code is doing what it is supposed to.  If you aren't expecting the "dip" in your graph, then you might have problems with your data or some such.  It's not entirely clear what you want to "fix"

Comment: It is not about the dip rather it is about the red colour curve in the last plot of the subplot. I did not mention it anywhere but still, it is appearing. I just need the blue curve and green curve

Comment: Perhaps this line: `p1=plt.plot(x_axis,Clean_Current_TEST,"g",x_axis,Clean_Current_Prediction1,"r--")` is the culprit?  It is hard to troubleshoot without "runnable" code provided.

Comment: thanks for the help, it really worked. the problem was with this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that recreates the problem you are experiencing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,1,20)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
y3 = np.arctan(x)

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)

plt.plot(x, y3, "g", x, y1, "r--")

ax1.plot(x, y3, "g", x, y1, "r--", lw=3.0)
ax2.plot(x, y3, "g", x, y2, "b--", lw=3.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

It seems that the `plt.plot` function actually plots its graph on the *last* axis.  This is why you are seeing the "red" graph on the last axis, even though the line that plots on axis 2 explicitly calls for a "blue" line.  In general, if you are plotting separate things on various axes, then you should not use the convenience methods in `matplotlib.pyplot`, and should instead use the methods on the `Axis` objects.

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)

ax1.plot(x, y3, 'g', x, y1, "r--", lw=3.0)
ax2.plot(x, y3, 'g', x, y2, "b--", lw=3.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]